# Coding a BBS Server in java

Tags: java

After looking at the Google BBS project the other day I quite liked the idea of coding a new front end for our enterprise app that would be a bbs.

This bbs server would then call various webservices etc.. all fine, all done before.

The question I have is that I have made a telnet server before, connected from a client and talked and send data, but how do I get the BBS look, i.e being able to put the cursor where I want it, receive movement (via arrow keys) commands to move about and place a status (mock) bar at the bottom. Get the text scrolling up effect as a new screen is drawn (but not the status bar)

So the question is using a telnet tech the best way to do this, or how can I achieve this look using another tech?

Comment: A user-interface like lynx? Using lynx as web browser, you could concentrate on a web app. I can hardly believe your aims, in the time of smart phone apps. But good luck.

Comment: Its just a fun project to connect to our cutting edge enterprise app.. A bit of fun really.. nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

Ok.. found this seems to be the answer I needed:

http://www.retrogradebbs.com/projects/cbbs/history.html

Cheers